# How do I reclaim reserved space in the sysjobstepslogs table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, msdb

I have a 36GB msdb database in my SQL Server 2008 R2 database server.  From what I have read this is past the point of being gigantic.  When I look at the tables in the msdb database the sysjobstepslogs table is using 97% of the space in the database.  I've done enough research to find out that the cause was several jobs had steps that had the Log to table option set + long running transactions + snapshot isolation on the msdb database.  This option has been disabled on those jobs.

I have tried to reduce its size by doing a truncate table, reindex, reorganize, check table, shrink file, shrink database (pretty much in that order) but with 0 rows, the sysjobstepslogs table still indicates that is has 35+GB reserved and used.

It has been suggested that I disable then reenable snapshot isolation to try to free up the space but according to [this MSDN forum discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b2a3db8a-ecea-497c-917c-5f668dcd93ef/master-msdb-database-by-default-in-snapshot-isolation-level) 
you cannot disable snapshot isolation on the msdb database.

I have contemplated dropping and recreating the table but how do I recreate the table as a system table and even if I did, is such a thing wise?

Any ideas how to reclaim this space?

Comment: Even if you could, no, that is not wise.

Answer (score 2):

You could try just rebuilding the table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.sysjobstepslogs REBUILD;
```

If you're on Enterprise (or Evaluation or Developer) you can do:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.sysjobstepslogs REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON);
```

The table only has a single clustered index (`PK_SomeAwfulGUID-basedName`) and this rebuild operation should deallocate all of the pages that might still be associated with the table.

Comment: I'm going to give this a try, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Chuck So how did it go?